# Notepad++ Generate Numbers By Increment

Tags: notepad++

I would like to generate a numbers of upto 100 and each with a fraction Like

1.1
1.2
1.3
1.4
....
1.9

then
2
2.1
2.3
2.4
.....
2.9
3
3.1

Upto 100

Can any one help me how to achieve this and if it is possible to do with Notepad++ or any other online, offline tool.

Thanks

Comment: https://catonmat.net/tools/generate-fractions - this tool might be useful

Answer (score 0):

If you have python compiler you can use this code from anywhere, including Notepad++

```
a = [i/10 for i in range(1*10, 100*10)]
print(a)
```

I also found this online compiler https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/online-compiler/ that you can run your code.